# Notification opening Google play

Tags: java, android

I would like make a notification when clicking open Google Play.

I'm using a google Api example.

Another question is, the notification Id can be static one?

Is neceesary add some other stuff in androidmanifest?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!");
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 2):

**Notification** ID is only for Notification identification and also if the previous notification is still visible, the system updates it from the contents of the **Notification** object. If the previous notification has been dismissed, a new notification is created instead.

You must add your intent ResultActivity into your manifest.xml file and also if you set Notification sound then you must add [Vibrate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#VIBRATE) permission into your manifest.xml file that's it.